# Java AES/CBC/NOPADDING equivalent in Python3

Tags: java, python-3.x, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

Im working on a custom protocol that works via UDP. The packets sent across the network are encoded with AES/CBC/NOPADDING algorithm in a JAVA client.

Im using a python3 client, so i need to decrypt this packets. My question is if there is any implementation of AES/CBC/NOPADDING in python3.

Im currently using this to decode in python:

```
def decrypt(key, data):
    from Crypto.Hash.MD5 import MD5Hash
    if data is None:
        return None
    cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf8'), AES.MODE_CBC, bytes([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]))
    return cipher.decrypt(data)
```

But the data return is random and not well decoded.

However, i can succesfuly decode the packets in java like this:

```
            Cipher cipher;

        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
                try {
                    cipher.doFinal(buffer, *** ...);            
                } catch (ShortBufferException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here i put a working example:
Firstr, i encrypt on java:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.ShortBufferException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String keyBytes = "UfrGUmAJq86pVtkd";
        String text_to_encrypt = "topotatopotatota";

        SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes.getBytes(), "AES");
        byte [] iv = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        Cipher cipher;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
                try {
                    String test = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(text_to_encrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));    
                    System.out.println(test);
                } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | UnsupportedEncodingException | BadPaddingException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Late i decode in python:

```
from hashlib import md5
from base64 import b64decode
from base64 import b64encode

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad


class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = md5(key.encode('utf8')).digest()

    def decrypt(self, data):
        raw = b64decode(data)
        self.cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, bytes([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]))
        return self.cipher.decrypt(raw)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    key = "UfrGUmAJq86pVtkd"
    expectedt_result = "topotatopotatota"
    encrypted_data = "ynCF3bJejxlLn1aAk8vcAw=="
    cipher = AESCipher(key)
    decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_data)
    print(decrypted_data)
```

Comment: The Python code works for me. Post test data that can be used to reproduce the problem. The PyCryptodome code corresponds to AES/CBC/NoPadding, since PyCryptodome does not implicitly pad/unpad.

Comment: The problem could be anywhere, this code is missing many, many important details. A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would go a long way here.

Comment: Hello @PresidentJamesK.Polk, you are right so i edited the post. Now you have a two working examples where encrypting is not working.

Comment: You must not hash the key with MD5 in the Python code, as this does not happen in the Java code either. Instead: `self.key = key.encode('utf8')`. With this decryption works with the Python code.

Comment: Yes! It was that @Topaco !! Thank you!!